# Recommended TFS branch structure for multiple developers

Tags: tfs

I am no TFS Master. In my previous company I've used tfs for source control but it was already structured by some consultant. The structure is like this

```
 $/Main
    -Project Framework
    -Project Application
    -Project Utilities
    -Project Web
  -Development
    -Project Framework
    -Project Application
    -Project Utilities
    -Project Web
  -DEV1
     -Project Framework
     -Project Application
     -Project Utilities
     -Project Web
  -DEV2
     -Project Framework
     -Project Application
     -Project Utilities
     -Project Web
```

After each development we would check in to our node, then merge to development, check in then merge to Main and check in.

Now I'm a new company and we did the structuring on our own. Our current structure is just

```
$/Main
  -Project Framework
  -Project Application
  -Project Utilities
  -Project Web
```

I suggested that we do the same thing like my previous company but I can't explain why. In my mind the reason why I wanted it is so that if I accidentally mess the project I can still pull the development copy, and main copy is always the approved or working code.

am I right?

Comment: Take a look at the following article, which describes the advantages and disadvantages of various branching strategies: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/branching-strategies-with-tfvc

Comment: thanks! great stuff..been typing strategies for tfs or typical tfs structure.

Comment: Looks like the link is dead - here's the new link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code is an important asset in your development effort. But it can be a challenge to effectively manage and evolve source files when multiple developers work concurrently on file updates. A key element in version control is branching that enables simultaneous development. If you branch strategically, you can maintain the order and consistency of multiple versions of your software.

Including the link @Joe provided, you can also check article [Branch strategically](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/branch-strategically), and find which branch strategy is suitable for your new company.